# What is the point to bind Ninject Kernel ToConstant and use InTransientScope?

Tags: c#, kernel, ninject

I want to bind IServiceProvider to Ninject IKernel implementation. What is the point to use

```
Bind<IKernel>().ToConstant(this).InTransientScope();
```

binding from Ninject [sources](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/KernelBase.cs) ?

This is the way how Ninject bind IKernel to KernelBase implementation. I can't understand the point. ToConstant binding type set scope to Singleton implicitly. And TransientScope with ToConstant binding type does not give any sense to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ToConstant` has two primary effects:

- ninject keeps a strong reference to the "constant" through the whole lifetime of the kernel
- the scope is configured to Singleton scope.

Now the call to `.InTransientScope()` after `ToConstant` changes the scope from Singleton back to transient.

What does this change? "transient" objects will not be disposed by ninject. For `Singleton` objects, if they're disposable, ninject will dispose them when the kernel is disposed. It's not doing that for "transient" objects.

So if the kernel would be bound `.InSingletonScope()`, doing `kernel.Dispose()` would result in another call to `kernel.Dispose()` - maybe even a Stack Overflow.